# MVC searching for view in wrong location

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Base URL to run the my MVC app is:
http://localhost/RealSuiteApps/RealHelp/-1/Inbox/

And... I get this exception:

[image]

I know what it means :) But I dont understand why I get it, I have everything in place and the exact same code was working perfectly yesterday. **What could go wrong?**

Here is the code, you see I have InboxController, Index action in it, and of course the view under Views/Inbox/Index view

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, this is a routing issue. Based on the error message, the `Index` action that's being loaded is actually in `HomeController`. MVC is searching `/Views/Home/` for the view, so that means the controller is `HomeController`. You should probably post your `RouteConfig.cs` file for a more thorough answer, but generally, I can tell you that you need to look at your routes and figure out why the URL is not going where it should.

Comment: Yes, weird, especially that this whole solution was working just fine until today, and there was no code change from yesterday, just in case I make backups of my projects every day at the end of the day, and I compared previous version and the current one... and they are identical.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is not with the solution itself, but maybe with installed ASP.NET MVC suddenly screwed up somehow? Cause after this error, I began to receive ViewBag is not defined, meaning something wrong with MVC installation... As for the routing - its empty, no routes defined, I may assume - its the default built-in route.